# Why is it faster to attach the visual debugger to my program than to run it directly from visual studio?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2012

I have been struggling with performance issues for quite a while, and I have recently realized that the performance I obtain when running from visual studio don't mean anything.

What surprises me much, though, is that I have very different performances depending on how I debug: When I run my program from visual studio, even in release mode, it is more than 10 times slower than when I run my program directly and then attach it to the visual studio debugger. Do you know where this difference comes from ?

Comment: Running performance tests with a debugger is absurd, no matter how you start the debugging session. Debug the program, once it works build in release mode and measure performance **without** interference from a debugger

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Not really. If you're using instrumenting profiler, debug build will give you better line-by-line information than release build.

Comment: @SigTerm: at any rate (I won't enter the discussion of whether building debug or release with symbols), running inside the debugger will incur extra costs that will make the performance measurements incorrect [Note: not saying that you cannot get profiling information (% of time spent in different parts), just that it won't be the real picture and it will not be **performance** information]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual inserts plenty of tests into your executable at runtime when you run it into the debugger:

- Heap corruption checks
- Stack corruption checks
- Mem leaks checks
- some even more subtle, especially if you run CRT

It does so by inserting a custom memory allocator library that supersedes the standard one.
All your calls to `new`, `delete` and all your stack operations (entering/exiting a function) are watched...

So yeah, for performance analysis, don't run into the VS debugger.

If you want to unroll what's happening in your code, you can take a look at the answer here:
[Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Especially the second answer that has interesting pointers.
One of the tools suggested is *very* useful: http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy

Comment: Raymond Chen has covered this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/03/10381959.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Even if you build in release mode, the default run mode in VS is to attach the debugger (which is always slower because it inserts a bunch of checks and monitoring). If you want to test a 'normal' run from within VS, use 'Debug>Start Without Debugging' or Ctrl-F5.